# How can I get the data in the form I need?

Tags: json, angular

ts:

```
  hours: Hour[];
  pieChart = [];

  load() {
    this._hoursService.fetch(this.user).subscribe((hours: Hour[]) => {
      this.hours = hours
      this.pieChart = [{
        name: hours.map(item => item.activity),
        y: hours.map(item => item.hours)
      }]
    console.log(this.pieChart)
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

I end up with a json result like this:

```
[{…}]
  0:
   name: (4) ["Tasks", "Meeting", "Mail", "Calls"]
   y: (4) [79, 12, 7, 2]
```

And in order for the data to begin to be displayed in the chart, the result should be like this:

```
[{
   name: 'Tasks',
   y: 79
}, {
   name: 'Meeting',
   y: 12
},
...]
```

How to do it?

hours:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {id: 1, activity: "Tasks", hours: 79, user: 1}
    1: {id: 2, activity: "Meeting", hours: 12, user: 1}
    2: {id: 3, activity: "Mail", hours: 7, user: 1}
    3: {id: 4, activity: "Calls", hours: 2, user: 1}
```

Comment: Can you post the response of the hours array?

Comment: @MuhammadKamran Added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
this.pieChart = hours.map(hour => ({name : hour.acitivty , y : hour.hours}) )
```